# Why did my Powershell Extensions stop working in Visual Code?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I have the lastest version of Visual Code installed on my Windows Server 2022 machine.
I have the Powershell Extensions installed in Visual Code

Initially Intellisense and the ability to run selected Powershell script from the file were working. Now, they've suddenly stopped working. Intellisense does nothing, nor does attempting to run a simple Powershell cmd via **F8**.

If I look at the Visual Code bottom status bar, it looks like Powershell does not start. The Progress indicator just keeps spinning.

**This is the contents of my exthost.log file:**

> 2023-02-03 19:48:33.473 [info] Extension host with pid 12980 started
> 2023-02-03 19:48:33.522 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension
> ms-vscode.powershell, startup: false, activationEvent:
> 'onLanguage:powershell' 2023-02-03 19:48:33.580 [info]
> ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension ms-vscode.powershell-preview,
> startup: false, activationEvent: 'onLanguage:powershell' 2023-02-03
> 19:48:33.626 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension
> vscode.emmet, startup: false, activationEvent: 'onLanguage' 2023-02-03
> 19:48:33.633 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension
> vscode.git-base, startup: true, activationEvent: '*', root cause:
> vscode.git 2023-02-03 19:48:33.636 [info]
> ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension EditorConfig.EditorConfig,
> startup: true, activationEvent: '*' 2023-02-03 19:48:33.691 [info]
> ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension johnpapa.vscode-peacock,
> startup: true, activationEvent: '*' 2023-02-03 19:48:33.698 [info]
> ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension mhutchie.git-graph, startup:
> true, activationEvent: '*' 2023-02-03 19:48:33.732 [info]
> ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension oderwat.indent-rainbow, startup:
> true, activationEvent: '*' 2023-02-03 19:48:33.734 [info]
> ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vsls-contrib.codetour, startup:
> true, activationEvent: '*' 2023-02-03 19:48:33.745 [info]
> ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vsls-contrib.gistfs, startup:
> true, activationEvent: '*' 2023-02-03 19:48:33.763 [info]
> ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vsls-contrib.gitdoc, startup:
> true, activationEvent: '*' 2023-02-03 19:48:33.823 [error] Activating
> extension ms-vscode.powershell-preview failed due to an error:
> 2023-02-03 19:48:33.823 [error] Error: command 'PowerShell.ShowLogs'
> already exists    at s.registerCommand
> (c:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS
> Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:96:106489)
> at Object.registerCommand
> (c:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS
> Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:117:29961)
> at new qa
> (c:\Users\Administrator.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-preview-2023.2.0\out\main.js:133:9998)
> at SM
> (c:\Users\Administrator.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-preview-2023.2.0\out\main.js:133:13021)
> at Ui.db (c:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS
> Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:108:14818)
> at Ui.cb (c:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS
> Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:108:14519)
> at c:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS
> Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:108:12519
> at async f.n (c:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft
> VS
> Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:6818)
> at async f.m (c:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft
> VS
> Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:6781)
> at async f.l (c:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft
> VS
> Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:6238)
> 2023-02-03 19:48:33.871 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension
> vscode.git, startup: true, activationEvent: '*' 2023-02-03
> 19:48:33.904 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension
> vscode.github, startup: true, activationEvent: '*' 2023-02-03
> 19:48:33.958 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension
> vscode.github-authentication, startup: false, activationEvent:
> 'onAuthenticationRequest:github' 2023-02-03 19:48:34.030 [error]
> Activating extension vsls-contrib.gitdoc failed due to an error:
> 2023-02-03 19:48:34.030 [error] Error: Git model not found    at
> s.getAPI (c:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS
> Code\resources\app\extensions\git\dist\main.js:2:1937819)     at
> c:\Users\Administrator.vscode\extensions\vsls-contrib.gitdoc-0.1.0\out\git.js:28:34
> at Generator.next ()     at fulfilled
> (c:\Users\Administrator.vscode\extensions\vsls-contrib.gitdoc-0.1.0\out\git.js:5:58)
> 2023-02-03 19:48:34.031 [info] Eager extensions activated 2023-02-03
> 19:48:34.047 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension
> vscode.debug-auto-launch, startup: false, activationEvent:
> 'onStartupFinished' 2023-02-03 19:48:34.050 [info]
> ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.merge-conflict, startup:
> false, activationEvent: 'onStartupFinished' 2023-02-03 19:48:34.061
> [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension
> ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl-recommender, startup: false,
> activationEvent: 'onStartupFinished' 2023-02-03 19:48:34.070 [info]
> ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension bierner.color-info, startup:
> false, activationEvent: 'onStartupFinished' 2023-02-03 19:48:34.074
> [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension eamodio.gitlens, startup:
> false, activationEvent: 'onStartupFinished' 2023-02-03 19:48:34.109
> [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension
> GitHub.vscode-pull-request-github, startup: false, activationEvent:
> 'onStartupFinished' 2023-02-03 19:48:34.184 [info]
> ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension Gruntfuggly.todo-tree, startup:
> false, activationEvent: 'onStartupFinished' 2023-02-03 19:48:34.202
> [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension
> ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers, startup: false, activationEvent:
> 'onStartupFinished' 2023-02-03 19:48:34.228 [info]
> ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl,
> startup: false, activationEvent: 'onStartupFinished' 2023-02-03
> 19:48:34.238 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension
> rangav.vscode-thunder-client, startup: false, activationEvent:
> 'onStartupFinished' 2023-02-03 19:48:34.459 [info]
> ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension usernamehw.errorlens, startup:
> false, activationEvent: 'onStartupFinished' 2023-02-03 19:48:34.461
> [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension
> vscode-icons-team.vscode-icons, startup: false, activationEvent:
> 'onStartupFinished' 2023-02-03 19:48:34.626 [info]
> ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.microsoft-authentication,
> startup: false, activationEvent: 'onAuthenticationRequest:microsoft'
> 2023-02-03 19:48:35.718 [error] Error: Git model not found    at
> s.getAPI (c:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS
> Code\resources\app\extensions\git\dist\main.js:2:1937819)     at new _p
> (c:\Users\Administrator.vscode\extensions\github.vscode-pull-request-github-0.58.0\dist\extension.js:1526:24442)
> at _p.createProvider
> (c:\Users\Administrator.vscode\extensions\github.vscode-pull-request-github-0.58.0\dist\extension.js:1526:25179)
> at async $0
> (c:\Users\Administrator.vscode\extensions\github.vscode-pull-request-github-0.58.0\dist\extension.js:1526:31243)
> at async Zm
> (c:\Users\Administrator.vscode\extensions\github.vscode-pull-request-github-0.58.0\dist\extension.js:1555:5616)
> at async eg
> (c:\Users\Administrator.vscode\extensions\github.vscode-pull-request-github-0.58.0\dist\extension.js:1555:6721)

I've tried uninstalling/installing the Powershell Extensions and Visual Code.
I've tried rebooting my machine several times.
Nothing seems to work so far.

I did the same installation process on a Windows Server 2019 box, and it works fine.
I installed on a Windows 10 machine and Intellisense does not work, although using F8 does.

To add more weirdness, I also see "Get Help for Command and "Run Selection" occur twice in my popup context menu in ps file I'm editing. That makes me believe that something is truly hosed with the install. I've tried uninstalling (Add - Remove) and rebooting. I still get the same results.

From doing some reading, it seems like Visual Code can be flakey when it comes to Powershell.

How do I figure out what the issues are and fix them?

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/4136. Are you using multi-root workspaces?

Comment: I think an application is already running that is using the log file.  Try rebooting.  Maybe in install a service that is using the file. : Activating extension ms-vscode.powershell-preview failed due to an error: 2023-02-03 19:48:33.823 [error] Error: command 'PowerShell.ShowLogs' already exists at s.registerCommand (c:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:96:106489)

Comment: @user - no idea what multi-root workspaces are, I just did default stuff out of the box... Can you pls explain? Thx

Comment: To find out what multi-root workspaces are, google `vscode multi-root workspaces` and click [the first link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces).

Comment: Went back to an older version of Visual Code and it works now (1.46)